# How to add a footer to a FlowDocument in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

I have a `FlowDocument` in my application which looks like as follows:

```
   <FlowDocumentScrollViewer Grid.Row="1">
        <FlowDocument>
              <Section>
                    <Paragraph>Header</Paragraph>
               </Section>

               <Section>
                  <Paragraph >
                        Footer
                   </Paragraph>
               </Section>
        </FlowDocument>
   </FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

What I want is to set the first `<Section>` to stay at the top of the document as a Header and the second one to stay at the bottom of the document as a footer.

Can anyone tell me the best way to do this?

Comment: I found this to be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759018/printing-a-flowdocument-with-dynamic-data-in-wpf

Answer (score 4):

The starting point is a blog post which shows [how to wrap a `DocumentPaginator` and add decoration to the pages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fyuan/archive/2007/03/10/convert-xaml-flow-document-to-xps-with-style-multiple-page-page-size-header-margin.aspx). The limitation is that it is intended for use directly with printing APIs. It can't be used directly with the viewers, because they require their documents to be `FlowDocument`, and it's not possible to override `DocumentPaginator` in a subclass.

The solution I've found for `FlowDocumentPageViewer` has a few parts. I haven't tried to adapt it to `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`, but it may be possible using the same principles.

#### Custom XAML template

I started by using Blend to extract the default XAML template for `FlowDocumentPageViewer`. I actually wanted to remove some bits anyway, but the key changes for headers/footers are (as unified diffs)

```xml
-    <Style TargetType="{x:Type FlowDocumentPageViewer}">
+    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomFlowDocumentPageViewer}">
```

```xml
                         <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Uid="Border_47" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                             <AdornerDecorator ClipToBounds="True" Uid="AdornerDecorator_1">
-                                <DocumentPageView DocumentPaginator="{x:Null}" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False" DocumentViewerBase.IsMasterPage="True" PageNumber="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" Uid="DocumentPageView_1"/>
+                                <DocumentPageView DocumentPaginator="{x:Null}" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False" DocumentViewerBase.IsMasterPage="True" PageNumber="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local" Uid="DocumentPageView_1" x:Name="DocumentPageView_1"/>
                             </AdornerDecorator>
                         </Border>
```

#### Subclass the viewer

As you should be able to work out from the XAML diff, my subclass is called `CustomFlowDocumentPageViewer`. Since `FlowDocumentPageViewer` requires its `Document` to be a `FlowDocument`, there's no point trying to change the document. But what I can do is intercept it and wrap its `DocumentPaginator` in a custom one, which I inject into the `DocumentPageView`.  The second half of the XAML diff is to enable me to find it.

```csharp
        private DocumentPageView _PageView;

        public DocumentPaginator CustomDocumentPaginator { get; private set; }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            _PageView = (DocumentPageView)GetTemplateChild("DocumentPageView_1");
            if (_PageView != null) _PageView.DocumentPaginator = CustomDocumentPaginator;
        }

        protected override void OnDocumentChanged()
        {
            base.OnDocumentChanged();

            var doc = Document as FlowDocument;
            CustomDocumentPaginator = doc == null ? null : new DocumentPaginatorWrapper((doc as IDocumentPaginatorSource).DocumentPaginator, new Thickness { Bottom = 32 /* 0.333in */ });
            if (_PageView != null) _PageView.DocumentPaginator = CustomDocumentPaginator;
        }
```

Of course, there's one big problem with only changing `DocumentPageView.DocumentPaginator`: if you call `myCustomFlowDocumentPageViewer.Print()` then it will print the original document, without headers and footers. The solution is simple but longish (about 100 lines); if you use [`referencesource.microsoft.com`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/SinglePageViewer.cs,67cec1b30591d1a8) you should be able to figure out how to override `OnPrintCommand` to send `CustomDocumentPaginator` to the `XpsDocumentWriter` instead of `((IDocumentPaginatorSource)document).DocumentPaginator`.

#### Wrap the document paginator

I said that the starting point is a blog post which shows how to wrap a `DocumentPaginator`. There are some subtleties which it didn't mention, probably because it was intended for printing a document once and so the author didn't run into them.

1. `DocumentPage` is disposable. When you get a page from the wrapped paginator, it's your responsibility to dispose of it. If you don't, you may find that as you navigate to and fro you get random `ArgumentException: Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget` when adding the wrapped page's `Visual` to your `ContainerVisual`.
2. Another way of getting that `ArgumentException` is to try to wrap the page when you already have a wrapped copy of the page around. E.g. this can happen if you print, because the `XpsDocumentWriter` will request a copy of the page which is currently being rendered to screen.

So you need to manage the lifecycles of the pages carefully. My modified version of the paginator wrapper is

```csharp
    class DocumentPaginatorWrapper : DocumentPaginator
    {
        private Thickness _Margin;
        private DocumentPaginator _Paginator;

        // Required to avoid "ArgumentException: Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget" when printing
        private IDictionary<int, DocumentPage> _PageCache = new Dictionary<int, DocumentPage>();

        public DocumentPaginatorWrapper(DocumentPaginator paginator, Thickness margin)
        {
            _Margin = margin;
            _Paginator = paginator;
            this.PageSize = paginator.PageSize;

            // Events
            paginator.ComputePageCountCompleted += (s, ev) => this.OnComputePageCountCompleted(ev);
            paginator.GetPageCompleted += (s, ev) => this.OnGetPageCompleted(ev);
            paginator.PagesChanged += (s, ev) => this.OnPagesChanged(ev);
        }

        public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
        {
            DocumentPage cachedPage;
            if (_PageCache.TryGetValue(pageNumber, out cachedPage) && cachedPage.Visual != null) return cachedPage;

            DocumentPage page = _Paginator.GetPage(pageNumber);

            // Create a wrapper visual for transformation and add extras
            ContainerVisual newpage = new ContainerVisual();

            // TODO Transform the wrapped page, add your headers and footers.
            // This is highly idiosyncratic.
            ...

            // NB We assume that page.BleedBox has X=0, Y=0, Size=page.PageSize
            cachedPage = new DocumentPageWrapper(page, newpage, PageSize, new Rect(PageSize), new Rect(page.ContentBox.X, page.ContentBox.Y, page.ContentBox.Width + _Margin.Left + _Margin.Right, page.ContentBox.Height + _Margin.Top + _Margin.Bottom));
            _PageCache[pageNumber] = cachedPage;
            return cachedPage;
        }

        public override bool IsPageCountValid { get { return _Paginator.IsPageCountValid; } }

        public override int PageCount { get { return _Paginator.PageCount; } }

        public override Size PageSize
        {
            get { var value = _Paginator.PageSize; return new Size(value.Width + _Margin.Left + _Margin.Right, value.Height + _Margin.Top + _Margin.Bottom); }
            set { _Paginator.PageSize = new Size(value.Width - _Margin.Left - _Margin.Right, value.Height - _Margin.Top - _Margin.Bottom); }
        }

        public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source { get { return _Paginator.Source; } }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// It's necessary to dispose the page returned by the wrapped DocumentPaginator when the page we return is disposed,
    /// because otherwise we inconsistently get ArgumentExceptions due to the page.Visual still being in use.
    /// </summary>
    class DocumentPageWrapper : DocumentPage
    {
        internal DocumentPageWrapper(DocumentPage originalPage, Visual visual, Size pageSize, Rect bleedBox, Rect contentBox)
            : base(visual, pageSize, bleedBox, contentBox)
        {
            _OriginalPage = originalPage;
        }

        private DocumentPage _OriginalPage;

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            base.Dispose();

            if (_OriginalPage != null)
            {
                _OriginalPage.Dispose();
                _OriginalPage = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your solution involves multiple steps of which some are not trivial. I find it hard to follow along. Do you have this solution somewhere as a working sample uploaded to the cloud from where it is possible to download?

Comment: @David, I'm afraid not. I did this at work, and I don't have a Windows box to reproduce it on, but if you can create a GitHub project with the bits you understand I can try to propose some patches for the rest. The Blend part is the only thing I don't think I could attempt without access to Windows and VS.

Comment: I get back to you as soon as I have something arranged. Will be really helpful.

Answer (score -2):

U can try this .. hope this helps..

```
<Section Name="MainBody" SectionExtensions.ResetPageNumbers="True">
    <!-- Add the document title to the header -->
    <SectionExtensions.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                <TextBlock Text="Document title" FontSize="16" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </SectionExtensions.HeaderTemplate>


    <!-- Add the page count to the footer -->
    <SectionExtensions.FooterTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="16" />
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </SectionExtensions.FooterTemplate>
    <Paragraph>
    ...
    </Paragraph>
</Section>
```